# Binding object from Inherit class to combobox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

Hello i have problems binding an inherit object of the type List, i can't figure out how to set the DisplayMember and ValueMember of the ComboBox

here is my class UserObject

```
using ComissionsTwo.Backend.Permissions;
using ComissionsTwo.Backend.SQL.User;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

namespace ComissionsTwo.Backend.User
{
    internal class UserObject
    {
        protected string userId;
        protected string userAlias;
        protected string userPassword;
        protected string userName;
        protected string userLastName;
        protected string userMail;
        protected string userIdRol;
        protected DataTable userData;
        protected DataTable userPermissions;
        protected SQLUser sqlUser = new SQLUser();
        protected RolesPermissionsOperations rolesPermissionsControl = new RolesPermissionsOperations();
        protected static List<UserObject> listOfUsers = new List<UserObject>();

        
        public UserObject(string userAlias, string userPassword)
        {
            this.userAlias = userAlias;
            this.userPassword = userPassword;
        }

        public UserObject(string userAlias)
        {
            this.userAlias = userAlias;
        }

        public UserObject()
        {
            
        }

    }
```

Here is my class from that i inherit my UserObject class, i call the method getListUsers() to get the list of users that will be binded to the combobox

```
using ComissionsTwo.Backend.Messages;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace ComissionsTwo.Backend.User
{
    internal class UserOperations : UserObject
    {
        public UserOperations(string userAlias, string userPassword) : base(userAlias, userPassword)
        {

        }

        public UserOperations(string userAlias) : base(userAlias)
        {
           
        }

        public UserOperations() : base()
        {

        }


        internal bool getUsers()
        {
            listOfUsers.Clear();
            DataTable aliasUsers = sqlUser.getUsers();
            foreach (DataRow row in aliasUsers.Rows)
            {
                UserOperations user = new UserOperations(row[0].ToString());
                if (user.getInfo() == false)
                {
                    MessagesInfo.StatusMessage = "No se pudo obtener la información de los usuarios activos";
                    return false;
                }
                listOfUsers.Add(user);
            }
            return true;
        }

        internal List<UserObject> getListUsers()
        {
            return listOfUsers;
        }

        internal bool addUser(DataTable userData, string userActiveId)
        {
            return sqlUser.addUser(userData, userActiveId);
        }

        internal bool editUser(DataTable userData, string userActiveId)
        {
            return sqlUser.editUser(userData, userActiveId);
        }

        internal bool eraseUser(string userId, string userActiveId)
        {
            return sqlUser.eraseUser(userId, userActiveId);
        }

        internal bool getUserPermissions()
        {
            userPermissions = rolesPermissionsControl.getUserPermissions(userIdRol);
            if (userPermissions == null || userPermissions.Rows[0][0].ToString() == string.Empty)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        internal bool getInfo()
        {
            if (loginInDatabase() == false)
            {
                MessagesInfo.StatusMessage = "No se pudo obtener la información del usuario a editar";
                return false;
            }
            else if (getUserPermissions() == false)
            {
                MessagesInfo.StatusMessage = "No se pudo obtener los permisos de usuario.";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        internal bool login()
        {
            if (loginInActiveDirectory() == false)
            {
                MessagesInfo.StatusMessage = "El usuario no pudo ser logeado en el directorio activo.";
                return false;
            }
            else if (loginInDatabase() == false)
            {
                MessagesInfo.StatusMessage = "El usuario no pudo ser logeado en la base de datos.";
                return false;
            }
            else if (getUserPermissions() == false)
            {
                MessagesInfo.StatusMessage = "No se pudo obtener los permisos de usuario.";
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        private bool loginInActiveDirectory()
        {

            string path = @"LDAP://192.168.0.15";       //CAMBIAR POR VUESTRO PATH (URL DEL SERVICIO DE DIRECTORIO LDAP)
                                                        //Por ejemplo: 'LDAP://ejemplo.lan.es'
            string domain = @"grupototal99.local";             //CAMBIAR POR VUESTRO DOMINIO
            string domainUser = domain + @"\" + userAlias;               //CADENA DE DOMINIO + USUARIO A COMPROBAR

            return autenticaUsuario(path, domainUser, userPassword);
        }

        private bool autenticaUsuario(string path, string user, string pass)
        {
            //Los datos que hemos pasado los 'convertimos' en una entrada de Active Directory para hacer la consulta
            DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path, user, pass, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
            try
            {
                //Inicia el chequeo con las credenciales que le hemos pasado
                //Si devuelve algo significa que ha autenticado las credenciales
                DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
                ds.FindOne();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                //Si no devuelve nada es que no ha podido autenticar las credenciales
                //ya sea porque no existe el usuario o por que no son correctas
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool loginInDatabase()
        {
            userData = sqlUser.getUser(userAlias);
            if (userData == null || userData.Rows[0][0].ToString() == string.Empty)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                userId = userData.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                userName = userData.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                userLastName = userData.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                userMail = userData.Rows[0][4].ToString();
                userIdRol = userData.Rows[0][5].ToString();
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my method to bind the comboBox

```
private void userEditComboBoxBinding()
        {
            BindingSource usersEditComboBoxBindingSource = new BindingSource();
            usersEditComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.usersEditComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
            usersEditComboBoxBindingSource.DataSource = user.getListUsers();
            usersEditComboBox.DataSource = usersEditComboBoxBindingSource.DataSource;
            usersEditComboBox.DisplayMember = "userAlias";
            usersEditComboBox.ValueMember = "userId";
            usersEditComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
            usersEditComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.usersEditComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
```

I have tried

```
usersEditComboBox.DisplayMember = "userAlias";
usersEditComboBox.ValueMember = "userId";
```

And

```
usersEditComboBox.DisplayMember = "UserAlias";
usersEditComboBox.ValueMember = "UserId";
```

But i always get and error if i commented usersEditComboBox.ValueMember the comboBox display this

ComissionsTwo.Backend.User.UserOperations the name of my class

Comment: Thank you, i edit it

Comment: Try expose the members of your class with a `public` property/field instead, not sure if it is required but it would make sense. Proxy property: `public string UserAlias { get { return userAlias; } }` and use it as `comboBox.DisplayMember = "UserAlias"`

Comment: @Fixation thank you, make a public getter was the solution